# Unable to close opened chat box in a web application

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried of closing the chat box by getting the element as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.icon")).click();
```

But its throwing exception of

> "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"

[image]

Comment: Can you share page `URL`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit wait to make sure its visible before clicking on it

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement closeButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.icon")));
closeButton.click();
```

Comment: @liki Check if this locator find more elements.